# Issue with multiple dup2s, forks, pipes and execs

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe, dup2

I am working on a shell(yes, it's an assignment, so I am not looking for a solution, more of a guide and clues to what I am doing wrong), and I'm stuck with pipes. I have read numerous tutorials, mans and what not, even copy-pasted some codes that "work", nothing seems to do the trick.

This is what I have so far:

```
void ft_run_pipe(char **cmd, int num)
{
int     i;
int     j;
int     piped[num][2];
pid_t   pid;

i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < num)
{
    ft_putstr("Creating pipe");
    ft_putnbr(i);
    ft_putchar('\n');
    if (pipe(piped[i]) < 0)
        ft_putstrn("piped failed");
    i++;
}
while (cmd[j] != '\0')
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('a');
        if (j != 0)
        {
            ft_putstrn("If not first");
            ft_putnbr(j - 1);
            if (dup2(piped[j - 1][0], 0) < 0)
            {
                ft_putstrn("dup1 failed");
                ft_putstrn(strerror(errno));
            }
            close(piped[j - 1][1]);
            close(piped[j - 1][0]);
        }
        if (j != num)
        {
            ft_putstrn("If not last");
            ft_putnbr(j);
            if (dup2(piped[j][1], 1) < 0)
            {
                ft_putstrn("dup2i failed");
                ft_putstrn(strerror(errno));
            }
            close (piped[j][0]);
            close (piped[j][0]);
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < num)
        {
            close(piped[i][0]);
            close(piped[i][1]);
            i++;
        }
    //  ft_run_special(cmd[j], environ);
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i < num)
        {
            close(piped[i][0]);
            close(piped[i][1]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    j++;
}
wait (NULL);
}
```

The various ft_something functions are coded by me alternatives to some libc functions(ft_putstr writes a string, with n in the end it adds a \n, etc.). ft_exec_special is a function that executes an executable with execve, searching in the PATH variable.

When ran with two commands and a single pipe, it returns

```
Creating pipe0
aIf not last
0aIf not first
0dup1 failed
Bad file descriptor
```

While, normally, it seems to me, it should work - piped[0][0] exists, is properly piped, and something was written to piped[0][1] - why would it say piped[0][0] is a bad file descriptor?

Comment: Study the source code of existing free software shells like [sash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [bash](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Use `strace` ...